# when to use test expression with if statement?

Tags: bash, shell-script

For bash scripting, I am confused about when to use the test expression with if statements.

For instance, the following works.

```
if finger | grep -q alex
```

But the following does not.

```
if [ finger | grep -q alex ]
```

However, I can do the following.

```
if [ 3 -gt 5 ]
```

So, when to use the test expression, and when not to? Also, is there a way to use the test expression with the commands above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the source of your confusion is that you don't know that `test` (AKA `[`) is just another command that returns a success (0) or failure (non-zero) result...either that or you don't fully understand the implications of that fact.

`if` is always run as:

```
if command; then
  do something
fi
```

with optional `elif` or `else` clauses.

That command can be `test` or `[` or `finger` or `grep` or anything else (even a long and complicated pipeline of commands), every program returns an exit code when it exits.  As @Kamil Maciorowski said in a comment, the only thing that matters to `if` is the exit code, it doesn't care where that exit code came from.

The fact that `test`/`[` is a built-in in many modern shells (including bash) doesn't really change that, it's just an optimisation to improve performance for a very commonly used command.  Before it was a built-in, it was `/usr/bin/test` and `/usr/bin/[` - in fact, these external versions of `test` and `[` still exist today (and are included in GNU coreutils even though also they're provided as built-ins to GNU bash).

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/test /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 68496 Sep 21 01:27 /usr/bin/[
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60304 Sep 21 01:27 /usr/bin/test

$ dlocate /usr/bin/test '/usr/bin/\['
coreutils: /usr/bin/[
coreutils: /usr/bin/test
```

BTW, from `help [` in bash:

```
[: [ arg... ]
    Evaluate conditional expression.
    
    This is a synonym for the "test" builtin, but the last argument must
    be a literal `]', to match the opening `['.
```

Comment: +1. In short: for `if` the exit status counts. `if` doesn't care what exact command it comes from. The answer to "when to use the test expression, and when not to?" is: if one wants `if` to depend on the exit status coming from `[` then one should use `[`; if one wants `if` to depend on the exit status of `grep` then one should use `grep` etc.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer. It's really appreciated. However, just as a word of advice my friend... Encouragement can generally go a long way. Some people would switch off if you start your answer by telling them how confused they are! Nonetheless, thank you for taking the time to explain stuff.

Comment: Nevermind @cas. Once again, thank you for your time, and have a great day ahead.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you, too. That summary is much appreciated.

Comment: @cas I would like to apologise for any offence caused. It was not my intention at all. In reality, your answer helped clarify my issues. So, I hope you take no hard feelings away from this!

Comment: no problem, i'm not offended, just puzzled about why you seemed to take offence.  being confused isn't a negative, isn't something to be ashamed of (especially when you're clearly trying to clear up that confusion - that's a good thing!)